# Java Types: What is the format for representing a variable of type `Date`? `Time`?

Tags: java

I have a varaibles:

```
Date date;
Time time;
```

and methods:

```
MyDateMethod(Date date){
//do stuff
}

MyTimeMethod(Time time){
//do stuff
}
```

I tried using `MyDateMethod()` with the following call:

```
MyDateMethod(1995-03-7);
```

I get an error saying I've supplied it with type `int` when it expected type `Time`.

I also tried using `MyTimeMethod()` with the following call:

```
MyTimeMethod(03:04:55);
```

I get an error saying `Type mismatch: Cannot convert type int to boolean.`

What is the format to put in a variable of these different types? `Date` is obviously not `xxxx-xx-xx` and `Time` is obviously not `xx:xx:xx`.

Comment: 1995-03-07 means 1995 minus three minus seven, which is 1985.

Comment: How did you even compile `Date date = 1995-03-07;` without getting a type mismatch error?

Comment: @azurefrog The OP didn't say that it compiled.

Comment: You need to read up on `SimpleDateFormat`.  It's the class that will convert the date from whichever format you want to supply it in, into a `Date` object.

Comment: I see 2 questions in your post, and FAIK non of them make sense. Can you rephrase your sentences, and add some [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Comment: @azurefrog I didn't actually have `Date date = 1995-03-07`. I have `Date date;`and then within a method call which takes a variable of type Date I put in `1995-03-07`. I just want to know what the correct format is for a variable of type `Date`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options,

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    Date d = sdf.parse("1995-03-07");
    System.out.println(d);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output is

```
    Tue Mar 07 00:00:00 EST 1995
```

Or, you could use

```
// -1 because January is 0... I didn't design it!
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(1995, 3 - 1, 7);
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

with the same output as before.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat is what You need. It's need to be initialized by format of date.

Use it like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
```

and then:

```
 Date date = (Date) dateFormat.parse("2014/04/02 22:22:22");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) and particularly [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Your example would be coded like this, using `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("1995-03-07")
```

(I'm assuming you have months before days here, you will need to interchange the MM and dd if not).

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support `Date` literals. You need to use a constructor or a static factory method to obtain an instance of this class.

`1995-03-07` returns `1985` because you have three `int` literals here and the hyphens are interpreted as subtraction operators.

Take a look at the documentation for the [`Date` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and the [`DateFormat` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

Here's a way you could represent these values:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("1995-03-07");

SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date time = timeFormat.parse("03:46:16");
```

You can use the same format objects to perform the reverse of this conversion. Please mind that these `Date` instances represent a specific moment in time, down to millisecond level. Internally, this is represented as the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

This API is hardly the prettiest one in Java and by looking at the docs you can see how many changes it has undergone. Just look at the number of deprecated methods.

I recommend taking a look at the [Joda-Time library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead.

Alternatively, if using Java 8 is an option for you, you can try the [brand new API that comes with it](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822730/642706) is correct. **No date-time literals** inJava.

And as he stated, the old bundled java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use either the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the new java.time package in Java 8.

## Joda-Time

In Joda-Time:

- If you want only a date without time and time zone, use the [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class.
- Similarly to use only time while ignoring time zone and date, use the [`LocalTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) class.
- But most often you'll probably want to use the [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class which tracks date, time, and time zone all in one object.

## A Date-Time Is *Not* Text

A DateTime object does *not* contain text. No String. If you need a string representation, use a formatter object to generate one. Search StackOverflow for many examples.

Built into Joda-Time are formatters for the sensible and increasingly common [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. For example, the `toString` implementation on the DateTime class produces a String like this…

```
2014-04-01T20:17:35-08:00
```